# How to handle two selects fields in a reactive Angular form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a screen where I create elements dynamically using reactive form, basically I create cards, where each has two selection fields:

[image]

**`Scenario:`** when I add a card and select a layout, the options of that specific layout are loaded in the select of assets through a service that makes the filter in the API, however when I add another card and select some other option in the layout select the two selects of assets are left with the same option.

[image]

#### Template

```
<div class="card"
  formArrayName="scriptOperationOrders" 
  *ngFor="let workstation of formOperation.get('scriptOperationOrders')['controls']; index as idx"
>
  <div class="card-body" [formGroupName]="idx">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>Rank</label>
        <input type="text" name="rank" class="form-control" formControlName="rank"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Layout</label>
        <select formGroupName="layout" (ngModelChange)="searchAssetsByLayouts($event)">
          <option value="">Choose Layout</option>
          <option 
            *ngFor="let lay of (layouts$ | async)?.dataArray " 
            [value]="lay.id">{{ lay.description }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Asset</label>
        <select formGroupName="asset">
          <option value="">Choose Asset</option>
          <option 
            *ngFor="let asset of (assets$ | async)?.dataArray " 
            [value]="asset.id">{{ asset.description }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
layouts$: Observable<IResponse<ILayoutModel>>;
assets$: Observable<IResponse<IAssetModel>>;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.buildFormOperation();
  this.layouts$ = this.layoutService.listLayouts();
  this.providers$ = this.providerService.listProviders();
}

buildFormOperation() {
  this.formOperation = this.fb.group({
    script: [],
    descriptionCode: [],
    description: [],
    scriptOperationOrders: new FormArray([])
  })
}

searchAssetsByLayouts(layoutId: number) {
  this.assets$ = this.assetService.listAssetsRoots(layoutId); // The assets$ variable is overridden here
}
```

#### Asset listing Service

```
listAssetsRoots(layoutId?: number | string): Observable<IResponse<IAssetModel>> {
  return this.apiService.crudeList({
    url: `${this.url}/roots`,
    queryParams: {
      layoutId
    },
  })
  .pipe(map((res) => {
    return new IResponse<IAssetModel>(res, IAssetModel);
  }));
}
```

> As you could be doing when selecting an option in the select layout, the options for that layout are loaded only in the select of assets on the same card

Comment: Can you add your service `listAssetsRoots` function?

Comment: Ok @ShayD , edited!

Comment: Can you debug your form array and ensure that you really have the items in it with the right index?

Comment: @ShayD Yes, they are correct, so much so that the rank field is filled with the +1 index. I store the return of the service listAssetsRoots () in the assets $ variable, I believe this is the problem, because when I change the option in the layout of the 2 card for example, the returned service fills in the variable but I use the same variable in the form, then all asset selects have the same options: `*ngFor="let asset of (assets$ | async) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.assets$ = this.assetService.listAssetsRoots(layoutId);` as The `assets$` variable is overridden here

ts file:-

```
//declared what type of response is expected 
interface Assets{
  id:number,
  description :string
}
//initially set to empty
assets$ : Observable<Assets[]> = of([]);


//accepting second argument idx as row_index
 
 searchAssetsByLayouts(layoutId: number,row_index:number) {
  this.assets$[row_index] = this.assetService.listAssetsRoots(layoutId); // The assets$ variable is no more overridden
}

//html:-
//here used formControlName for 'layout' and 'asset' control insted of formGroupName
//and passed 'idx' as second parameter  to (ngModelChange)="searchAssetsByLayouts($event,idx)

<div class="card"
  formArrayName="scriptOperationOrders" 
  *ngFor="let workstation of formOperation.get('scriptOperationOrders')['controls']; index as idx"
>
  <div class="card-body" [formGroupName]="idx">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>Rank</label>
        <input type="text" name="rank" class="form-control" formControlName="rank"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Layout</label>
        <select formControlName="layout" (ngModelChange)="searchAssetsByLayouts($event,idx)">
          <option value="">Choose Layout</option>
          <option 
            *ngFor="let lay of (layouts$ | async)?.dataArray " 
            [value]="lay.id">{{ lay.description }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Asset</label>
           <select formControlName="asset">
                  <option value="">Choose Asset</option>
                  <option 
                    *ngFor="let asset of (assets$[idx] | async)" 
                    [value]="asset.id">{{ asset.description }}
                  </option>
         </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woww... amazing man :) Thank you very much, helped me a lot!!!